# Terraform Error: error waiting for sagemaker notebook instance to create: unexpected state 'Failed', wanted target 'InService'. last error: %!s(<nil>)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker

The entire error message after executing `terraform apply` within the terraform-folder of [this source code in my GitHub-repo](https://github.com/AndreasLuckert/aws-sm-notebook-instance) (inspired by [this tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/terraform-sagemaker-part-2a-creating-custom-notebook-instance-david) and [its related GitHub-repo](https://github.com/dkhundley/terraform-sagemaker-tutorial)):

```
aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.notebook_instance: Creating...
aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.notebook_instance: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.notebook_instance: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
...
aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.notebook_instance: Still creating... [15m21s elapsed]
aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.notebook_instance: Still creating... [15m31s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: error waiting for sagemaker notebook instance (aws-sm-notebook-instance) to create: unexpected state 'Failed', wanted target 'InService'. last error: %!s(<nil>)
│
│   with aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.notebook_instance,
│   on notebook_instance.tf line 2, in resource "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance" "notebook_instance":
│    2: resource "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance" "notebook_instance" {
│
```

Internet research seemed to provide the solution in [this article](https://yuyasugano.medium.com/machine-learning-infrastructure-terraforming-sagemaker-part-2-f2460a9a4663), which inspired be to increase the allowed `IDLE_TIME` in the `on-start.sh` - script to `IDLE_TIME=1800` (in seconds, which equals 30 minutes). This should've been sufficient for the deployment time of around 15 minutes; yet, it threw the same error again.

Next, I found [this post on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65884743/resolving-broken-deleted-state-in-terraform) suggesting to

> run `terraform refresh`, which will cause Terraform to refresh its state
> file against what actually exists with the cloud provider.

Unfortunately, running `terraform apply` right after refreshing didn't resolve the issue either.
I'm wondering why the aforementioned `IDLE_TIME=1800` - setting does not have any effect. This should be more than sufficient for a 15-minute apply-time.

---

**EDIT: adding code specifics for enhanced understanding**

**1. Creating the SageMaker notebook instance**

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance" "notebook_instance" {
  name                    = "aws-sm-notebook-instance"
  role_arn                = aws_iam_role.notebook_iam_role.arn
  instance_type           = "ml.t2.medium"
  lifecycle_config_name   = aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance_lifecycle_configuration.notebook_config.name
  default_code_repository = aws_sagemaker_code_repository.git_repo.code_repository_name
}
```

**2. Defining the SageMaker notebook lifecycle configuration**

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance_lifecycle_configuration" "notebook_config" {
  name      = "dev-platform-al-sm-lifecycle-config"
  on_create = filebase64("../scripts/on-create.sh")
  on_start  = filebase64("../scripts/on-start.sh")
}
```

**3. Defining the Git repo to instantiate on the SageMaker notebook instance**

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_code_repository" "git_repo" {
  code_repository_name = "aws-sm-notebook-instance-repo"

  git_config {
    repository_url = "https://github.com/AndreasLuckert/aws-sm-notebook-instance.git"
  }
}
```

**Contents of `on-start.sh` (including IDLE_TIME - parameter)**
Note that this script will be invoked by the `scripts/autostop.py` - script, which you can find [here](https://github.com/AndreasLuckert/aws-sm-notebook-instance/blob/main/scripts/autostop.py) in the associated [public repo containing the source code](https://github.com/AndreasLuckert/aws-sm-notebook-instance).

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

## IDLE AUTOSTOP STEPS
## ----------------------------------------------------------------

## Setting the timeout (in seconds) for how long the SageMaker notebook can run idly before being auto-stopped
# -> e.g. 1800 s = 30 min since first deployment can take between 15 and 20 minutes which could then fail like so:
# "Error: error waiting for sagemaker notebook instance (aws-sm-notebook-instance) to create: unexpected state 'Failed', wanted target 'InService'. last error: %!s(<nil>)"
# Hint for solution under following link: https://yuyasugano.medium.com/machine-learning-infrastructure-terraforming-sagemaker-part-2-f2460a9a4663
IDLE_TIME=1800

# Getting the autostop.py script from GitHub
echo "Fetching the autostop script..."
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreasluckert/aws-sm-notebook-instance/main/scripts/autostop.py

# Using crontab to autostop the notebook when idle time is breached
echo "Starting the SageMaker autostop script in cron."
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python $PWD/autostop.py --time $IDLE_TIME --ignore-connections") | crontab -



## CUSTOM CONDA KERNEL USAGE STEPS
## ----------------------------------------------------------------

# Setting the proper user credentials
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
unset SUDO_UID

# Setting the source for the custom conda kernel
WORKING_DIR=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda
source "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda/bin/activate"

# Loading all the custom kernels
for env in $WORKING_DIR/miniconda/envs/*; do
    BASENAME=$(basename "$env")
    source activate "$BASENAME"
    python -m ipykernel install --user --name "$BASENAME" --display-name "Custom ($BASENAME)"
done
```

Comment: Would you be able to post the actual code? Also, looking at the `IDLE_TIMEOUT` reference it is related to the time the notebook can be left idle, while this looks like it just times out, which is the AWS API for Sagemaker timeout I think.

Comment: You could also check if the Sagemaker API supports timeouts and if it does, take a look here how to add it: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/syntax.html#operation-timeouts.

Comment: All the code is in my public repo mentioned in the OP: https://github.com/AndreasLuckert/aws-sm-notebook-instance

Comment: If I understood correctly, I can insert something like `timeouts {create = "60m" delete = "2h"}` into my `resource "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance" "notebook_instance"` in order to prevent the error?

Comment: Unfortunately, it says: `Error: Unsupported block type - Blocks of type "timeouts" are not expected here.` I've also tried to include it in `"resource "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance_lifecycle_configuration" "notebook_config"`, but it throws the same error when doing `terraform refresh` or `terraform validate`.

Comment: Please kindly note that I've just added `terraform` and `bash`-code which should help understand more easily what is going on. Apart from that, all of the source-code employed can be looked at in the associated public `GitHub` repo: https://github.com/AndreasLuckert/aws-sm-notebook-instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to check the CloudWatch Log events under `CloudWatch -> Log groups -> /aws/sagemaker/NotebookInstances -> aws-sm-notebook-instance/LifecycleConfigOnCreate` to find the following error-message:

```
/bin/bash: /tmp/OnCreate_2021-09-08-12-24rw5al34g: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

A bit of internet research brought me to [this solution related to newline characters in shell-scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304999/not-able-to-execute-a-sh-file-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter/305001#305001), which depend on whether you are on `Windows` or a `UNIX`-system.
As I'm working on Windows, the shell-scripts created in VS-Code comprised dos-specific `CRLF` newline-handling, which could be resolved via the button on the bottom-right in `VS-Code` to switch the *carriage return* (CRLF) character to the *line feed* (LF) character used by UNIX.

As the compute instance employed by AWS Sagemaker is a Linux-system, it cannot handle the dos-style CRLF newline-characters in the shell-scripts and this "adds" a `^M` after `/bin/bash` which obviously leads to an error as such an interpreter does not exist.

So, finally `terraform apply` worked out well:

```
$ terraform apply
...
...
aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.notebook_instance: Still creating... [7m30s elapsed]
aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.notebook_instance: Still creating... [7m40s elapsed]
aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance.notebook_instance: Creation complete after 7m43s [id=aws-sm-notebook-instance]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 1 changed, 1 destroyed.
```